# Play Framework 1.2.7 - Refresh page with anchor

Tags: html, playframework

I am using this syntax to refesh the page I am in:

```
<a href="@{Instance.logs(instance?.id)}#end"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
```

The result of this command is, for example:

```
<a href="/instance/logs/1#end"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></a>
```

Which seems right.
This doesn't work with the anchor (#end), but works without. It only goes to the anchor, but never reload. Why is this? Is this only because I am in the same page, or is there another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's standard browser behavior, unrelated to Play. If the link contains an anchor and the user is already on the page the browser will just scroll to the anchor position.

Does it need to be an anchor? You could change it to a regular query string parameter (`/instance/logs/1?end`) and use javascript to check for the parameter and scroll the page.

Comment: Well I just need to reload the page and go to the end, I could have done it in JS but if I can handle it in pure HTML, it would be better! Thanks anyway for your answer :)

Comment: @Møønheart Well, you could keep the anchor and then add some randomly generated parameter to the url. The parameter should be enough to make the browser think it's a different page, and the anchor will still cause the page to scroll on load.